# Is there a more efficient way to do this if statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my if statement

```
if (
      currentPosition.id.includes("a") ||
      currentPosition.id.includes("b") ||
      currentPosition.id.includes("c") ||
      currentPosition.id.includes("d") ||
      currentPosition.id.includes("e") ||
      currentPosition.id.includes("f") ||
      currentPosition.id.includes("g")
    ) {}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: `function isPositionIncludes(str) {return currentPosition.id.includes(str)}`

Comment: If you want to alphabet range then, use `/[a-g]/.test(currentPosition.id)`. If it is any substring, then `/a|b|c|d|e|f|g/.test(currentPosition.id)` Separate each substring with a `|`